# VirtualBox unresponsive after a forced power down

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox

I have trouble in VirtualBox on Ubuntu 12.04 32bit. This app does not run after emergency switching off of the computer. See screenshot, virtualbox remains in this condition.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem after a reboot post-upgrading to 12.04 from 11.xx. I simply remove the virtualbox from Ubuntu Software Center and reinstall it after a reboot. It works just fine without loosing current OS we installed on the virtualbox.